# The Earth's climate has changed compared to the past/from what it used to be(synonyms)

Tags: synonyms

I was watching an English video when a **native** english speaker compared the PAST to the PRESENT. I usually use **''in the past/to the past''** to compare but the native chose ''it used to be'' instead, and then it popped into my head that it may be a good alternative to not sound repetitive.
Can I use this interchangeably:

> The Earth's climate has changed **compared to the past.**

And

> The Earth's climate has changed **from what it used to be.**

Are they the same? I think it is but I'm not 100% sure, and I might be misterpreted if I use it incorrectly in my future conversation.

Comment: Both are incorrect. You should explain why you wrote them the way you did. Basically, what is the comparison that "than" implies?

Comment: I have edited it, is it ok now?

Comment: The second one still doesn't make any sense.  The first one is OK, though.

Comment: There!? Hehe I think they are all grammatical now, aren't they..

Comment: "Changed" means different from what it used to be, so it is redundant to repeat that in a general reference to change.  It's like saying "The Earth's climate is different from what it used to be from what it used to be."  You would only need such qualification if it was a comparison to a specific previous time.  "The Earth's climate has changed compared to 1800."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use **has changed**, but not in the way you've constructed the sentences.

The following versions would work:

> The Earth's climate has changed from what it was in the past.
>   The Earth's climate has changed from what it used to be in the past.

However, **in the past** is somewhat redundant and could be dropped:

> The Earth's climate has changed from what it was.
>   The Earth's climate has changed from what it used to be.

Finally, most direct of all:

> The Earth's climate has changed.

Comment: Oh NICE, that's the word ''from what it was''!. You nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

There must be something that has degree in your statement in order to use **than**. For example:  big, cold, hot, wet, slow, rapid.

> The earth's climate is *hotter* today than in the past.
>
> The summer season is *wetter* this year than last.

The verb **has changed** does not have degree.

> Technological change is *more rapid* today than it was a century ago.

hotter ... than

wetter ... than

more rapid ... than

Comment: My apologies for that comparison conjunction. I've changed it now